# How to move an image inside an imagebox vb.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am currently making a textbased RPG in vb.NET as I felt like it. I have a whole movement system which tracks your current location and it has an x and y coordinate. To move the player must use the move command like this: "move north". I have a large map inside an image box with the size of 250x250 pixels as it seems to be the best size to use. What I want to do is be able to move the location of the picture by 250 pixels to the left, right or up or down every time they change their location by using the command.

I can't work out how I would easily move the image inside of the image box so it's shifted 250 pixels in any direction. I have Googled around and can't seem to find an answer that will work for me. If any of you masters of vb.NET have any idea how I could make this work, that would be great. There isn't any code I can give you as all of what I have researched has not worked.

I currently have this:

```
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform((Player.x * 100), (Player.y * 100))
```

And I can't work out how it works.

Thanks for the assistance,
Laurence.

Comment: You mean `myControl.Left += 250`?

Comment: No, so that the whole image, inside of the picturebox will move. Not the whole control.

Comment: You can't move images in the PictureBox if you set the Image property.  You would have to use the Paint event of the PictureBox control instead, which would require drawing the image yourself.

Comment: might be of interest: http://bobpowell.net/zoompicbox.aspx

Comment: A good craftsman never blames his tools.

Comment: ...actually MS **did** include it - use `Graphics.TranslateTransform` in your paint event - one line of code

Comment: How would that be implemented? I have this: e.Graphics.TranslateTransform((Player.x * 100), (Player.y * 100))

Comment: sorry wrong function - i thought you were trying to pan something, not animate smaller images on a canvas.  you just need to draw at different x,y locations (in paint)

Comment: So using Graphics.DrawImage?